# Blank(red point) before print values

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter, my program is fine in localhost but get mistakes online.
It's hard to describe but everything like pictures tell:

[image]
[image]

Even worse, if I write code in js like this:

```
var a='{"status":0,"message":"Operation succeed!"}';
var b=$.parseJSON('{"status":0,"message":"Operation succeed!"}');
```

It becomes:

[image]

And throw exceptions that I can't analyze JSON codes.

Comment: Can you check the remote file? `DOCTYPE` definition **must** be the first in html. No spaces and no newlines before, otherwise it will at least render in quirks mode and have arbitrary results.  The red dot indicates that there's "something" before the opening `<`

Comment: I don't know how it happens..@DarylGill

Comment: of course@AxelAmthor,I think it's server's problem and insert BOM head,I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This issue is caused by the [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of PHP files.

After using a text editor that allows me to remove the BOMs, the problem is gone.